# C# Outlook Form Region - Saving data, user properties?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

What is the correct way to save form region data from within an outlook item (appointment in this case) ?

What I'm basically trying to do is save all the form region data along with the outlook appointment, so opening up to edit the appointment the form region is populated as like the main appointment data would be.

I have managed to bind to the ItemSend event as the following, to set user properties on the item which I get from the populated form region:

```
private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem Appointment = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    Outlook.UserProperty MyProperty = Appointment.UserProperties.Add("form_region_control", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false);
    MyProperty.Value = this.AFormRegionControl.Text;
    Appointment.Save();
}
```

However, it doesn't seem like those user properties are actually being saved anywhere. I'm new to C# and outlook addins and I (perhaps falsely?) assumed that user properties were used to store custom data against an outlook item.

If that assumption is correct, how do I go about accessing them upon opening the saved item? Or if I'm incorrect, what is the correct way to get this data?

```
// Opening up an existing appointment, after it is saved with user props
if (appointment.UserProperties.Find("form_region_control") != null)
    // assign the property to the form control when opening an existing item??
```

The above always returns null, so I'm at a loss as to how I can access user properties... or maybe I am not saving them correctly? I have trawled through MSDN and google for any pointers but none give any more information other than how to create and save properties which is exactly what I'm doing above.

I've also tried using `ItemProperties` as well as `UserProperties`, both give the same result, as well as setting `AddToFolderFields` to both true and false.

**UPDATE:**
So switching from `ItemSend` on the Application object to the `Write` event and setting user properties on that I can now access these from within `FormRegionShowing` and set the properties manually on the FormRegion controls:

```
private void Appointment_Write(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.ItemProperty MyProperty = this.appointment.ItemProperties.Add("AFormRegionControl", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false);
    MyProperty.Value = this.AFormRegionControl.Text;
}

// and from within FormRegion_Showing ....
if (this.appointment.UserProperties.Find("AFormRegionControl") != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this.appointment.UserProperties.Find("AFormRegionControl").Value);
    this.AFormRegionControl.Text = this.appointment.UserProperties.Find("AFormRegionControl").Value;
}
```

I'd still be interested to know if this is the best way of doing this. It's a big form region so it will be laborious to manually set everything, but I haven't been able to find anything better so far.